# Computed signal time vector is slightly incorrect

Tags: matlab

I'm loading in a set of samples into Matlab, and I end up with a vector that is 69,632 samples long.

When I attempt to create the time vector for graphing purposes however, I cannot get it exact.  This is my approach:

```
Fs = 44100;                %44.1kHz sampling rate
Ts = 1/Fs;                 %Time spacing between samples
maxTime = Ts * len;        %Time of last data point  (len=69,632)
timeVector = 0:Ts:maxTime  %Create the time axis vector
```

So my computed timeVector ends up being 69,633 elements long, because the `1/Fs` calculation is slightly rounded up, and then when I multiply that result by len I suppose it just arrives at a larger number.

Can I get Matlab to not round? Or is there a better/correct way to get this time axis that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you start `t` from `0`,

```
  len = length(signal); % len = 69632;
  Ts = 1/44100;
  timeVector = (0 : len -1) * Ts;
```

Comment: Do you mean `maxTime-Ts` since in this case it would subtract 1 full second?

Comment: @krb686, Yes, actually I changed the code a bit, try that.

Comment: Thanks, a lot easier than I was expecting.